# What is the difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, database-security, sspi

I have two apps that use Integrated Security. One assigns `Integrated Security = true` in the connection string,  and the other sets `Integrated Security = SSPI`.

What is the difference between `SSPI` and `true` in the context of Integrated Security?

Comment: @PranavSingh has the right idea, this question is incomplete unless you specify which _provider_ you are using. Different providers accept and/or translate various strings into internal states.

Comment: Although they are same, I believe that there was a very old document in one of websites, at the time i was curious same as you, that said if you are developing for windows mobile (not what you see today, the old devices which i don't remember the OS suffix since i never had one), you should use SSPI, and User Password together. but since i never wrote one, and i don't remember the source of that document, i cannot guarantee it.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) they are the same thing.

> When `false`, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, and `sspi` (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to `true`.

Comment: Originally, I think there was a difference in that "True" used NTLM and "SSPI" used Kerberos, but they're now interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Any reason why it works with one and not the other? In fact, if recall correctly, the error obtained when I used "true" was about some driver (on a 2003 windows server with sql server express).

JD.

Comment: Didn't check last comment, but if true, should be as answer, but not the comment

Comment: @RodneyFoley I use SSPI with wrong username and password, but it doesnt care and connected successfully in net4.0. Is this expected result ?

Comment: @RodneyFoley Do you have a source for that statement? This seems unusual as integrated is preferred over SQL authentication, so a system that defaults to SQL auth seems unlikely.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst MSDN Doc's for connection strings, and real world usage.

Comment: @RodneyFoley sorry, wasn't clear enough. Can you provide a source for that statement? I'm googling it and can't find any such advice.

Comment: @RodneyFoley sorry, my tests confirm that this answer is correct and your comment is not. Maybe it worked that way once, but it doesn't now, and you can't provide any reference to a Microsoft doc that supports your opinion.

Comment: Agree with Kirk. User / password is ignored when SSPI specified - .net 4.0, SQL server 2012.

Comment: @RodneyFoley and @KirkBroadhurst:  Looking at other answers it looks like it might depend on the provider used.  If talking about `System.Data.SqlClient`, I did find [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#integratedsecurity) which says `True` means that `User Id` and `Password` will be ignored and `SSPI` means that they will be be used if present, but Windows Security will be used if not.  [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx) says true will ignore them but doesn't mention SSPI.

Comment: So if they "are the same thing" why is SSPI "strongly recommended" rather than "true" or "yes? That's the reason why I came to this question...

Comment: @PranavSingh: It's not me who is saying they are the same. Is the current answer which we are commenting...

Comment: @ZéCarlos Ok, Got it. Somehow that is accepted answer with highest votes :) . I added answer for same clarification

Comment: If it is only used to say you are using Windows Authentication, wonder why they didn't just call the setting/property "Windows Authentication" instead of Integrated Security?

Answer (score 246):

`Integrated Security=true;` doesn't work in all SQL providers, it throws an exception when used with the `OleDb` provider.

So basically `Integrated Security=SSPI;` is preferred since works with both `SQLClient` & `OleDB` provider.

Here's the full set of syntaxes according to [MSDN - Connection String Syntax (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

[image: ![Windows Auth Syntax]

Comment: Isn't this answer repeats the third rated one?

Comment: @Yola this answer is a bit more complete and also links to a still-valid Microsoft Docs page (the link in the other answer now brings you to a page suggesting to download Visual Studio 2005 Retired docs).

Answer (score 81):

***Using Windows Authentication***

To connect to the database server is recommended to use Windows Authentication, commonly known as integrated security. To specify the Windows authentication, you can use any of the following two key-value pairs with the data provider. NET Framework for SQL Server:

```
 Integrated Security = true;
 Integrated Security = SSPI;
```

However, only the second works with the data provider *.NET Framework OleDb*. If you set `Integrated Security = true` for ConnectionString an exception is thrown.

To specify the Windows authentication in the data provider. NET Framework for ODBC, you should use the following key-value pair.

```
Trusted_Connection = yes;
```

Source: [MSDN: Working with Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254978%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 38):

Many questions get answers if we use `.Net Reflector` to see the actual code of `SqlConnection` :)
`true` and `sspi` are the same:

```
internal class DbConnectionOptions

...

internal bool ConvertValueToIntegratedSecurityInternal(string stringValue)
{
    if ((CompareInsensitiveInvariant(stringValue, "sspi") || CompareInsensitiveInvariant(stringValue, "true")) || CompareInsensitiveInvariant(stringValue, "yes"))
    {
        return true;
    }
}

...
```

**EDIT 20.02.2018**
Now in .Net Core we can see its open source on github! 
Search for ConvertValueToIntegratedSecurityInternal method:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/fdbb160aeb0fad168b3603dbdd971d568151a0c8/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/Common/DbConnectionOptions.cs

Comment: That part of code is property only for one case that is explainable by name `ConvertValueToIntegratedSecurityInternal`. That property is used only when provider is `SqlClient` so in `SqlClient`, `SSPI` &`true` are same but not when client is `OleDb` or `OracleClient`. I have clarified that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23637478/704008 with msdn reference

Answer (score 27):

Integrated Security = False : User ID and Password are specified in the connection. 
Integrated Security = true : the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Integrated Security = SSPI : this is equivalant to true.

We can avoid the username and password attributes from the connection string and use the Integrated Security

Answer (score 20):

Let me start with `Integrated Security = false`

**`false`**  User ID and Password are specified in the connection string.
**`true`**  Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Recognized values are `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, and `SSPI`.

If `User ID` and `Password` are specified and Integrated Security is set to `true`, then `User ID` and `Password` will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used

Answer (score 8):

Note that connection strings are specific to **what** and **how** you are connecting to data. These are connecting to the same database but the first is using .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server. Integrated Security=True will not work for OleDb.

- Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True
- Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb

When in doubt use the Visual Studio Server Explorer Data Connections.

- What is [sspi](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742535.aspx)?
- [Connection Strings Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254500%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

True is only valid if you're using the .NET SqlClient library. It isn't valid when using OLEDB.
Where SSPI is bvaid in both either you are using .net SqlClient library or OLEDB.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b61c092b-48c8-4bc7-b26b-47b41ea72b69/is-there-a-difference-bt-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view,

If you dont use Integrated security=SSPI,then you need to hardcode the username and password in the connection string which means "relatively insecure" why because, all the employees have the access even ex-employee could use the information maliciously.

Comment: The connection string is not necessarily visible to any employee.

Comment: -1 If you don't use `Integrated security=SSPI` then you can use `Integrated security=true` and still not have to hardcode usernames and passwords. Moreover, securing these kinds of configurations is out of the scope of this question.