# Is there a difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI when used in the connection string. I could sense some difference between them throug i went through some document which says there is no difference.

Comment: See existing excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi They are equivalent in terms of the way authentication is performed but 'Integrated Security=SSPI' will try authenticate with user/pass if provided whereas 'Integrated Security=true' will just try straight away with current user account.

Comment: @Lisa do you have a test case or reference that indictes that SSPI will use user/pass in the connection string?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry no. Being in Java-based development for the past 4 years, I've not even touched SQL Server or C# in the meantime so it's not fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, they are two ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: ..except that one will not work with certain drivers.