# SQLException: Login failed for user ' ' JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, authentication

I'm trying to connect with the MS SQL database but everytime i try i get this error:

> SQLException: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated
>   with a trusted SQL Server connection.
>   ClientConnectionId:86b1da77-8eff-4c3f-badb-5ab75efcbab4 SQLState:
>   S0001 VendorError: 18452

I've already configured to 'SQL Server authentication' and 'enabled' at the login settings. I would be very grateful if someone could solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String database="sisqualPONTO";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:40000"+";DatabaseName=" + database+ ";integratedSecurity=true;";
String pass="****";
String user="sa";

try {
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,user,pass);
  System.out.println("Success");
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
  System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
  System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
  System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.
Cumps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `'integratedSecurity=true'` from your connection URL.