# how to connect a remote SQLserver using widows authentication from a .net application, if possible

Tags: c#, asp.net

currently I am using this connection string inside the app.config file of the application

```
add name="LightSailEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LightSailEntities.csdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.ssdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=abc.xyz.com;initial catalog=LightSail;user id=LightSail; password=yourpasswordhere;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

The domain of .Net application and the domain of client, using .Net application, is different from domain of SQL server. I mentioned **"using widows authentication"** only because of, I have the access of the server machine(means I can use Remote Desktop Connection) on which the SQL server is installed.

Comment: What have you tried? You shouldn't face any problem if the firewalls are set right

Comment: is your windows account added to the security table inside sqlserver?

Comment: WHy you give a password? Integrated security is no password and username, process must run in a AD integrated account. Not doing that, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Auth you don't need to set the User Id and Password but you do need to include 'Integrated Security=SSPI;'

Try:

```
add name="LightSailEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LightSailEntities.csdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.ssdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=dev.shopcube.com;initial catalog=LightSail;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

There's a bit more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx

Comment: For anyone who's interested, there is a difference between 'Integrated Security = True' (as mentioned by @Marcin) and 'Integrated Security = SSPI'. The details are covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi

Answer (score 1):

You have to change ConnectionString to use `Integrated Security=SSPI` insetad of `user` and `password`

```
add name="LightSailEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/LightSailEntities.csdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.ssdl|res://*/LightSailEntities.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string='data source=dev.shopcube.com;initial catalog=LightSail;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

After that, look at the `Identity` set for the `Application Pool` of you application.
**That user must be authorized to access your DB** using `Security\Logins` inside `Object Explorer` pan of Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Youo can use following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConn);
```

or if you use Linq2SQL:

`DBContext ctx = new DBContext(Configuration.DBConn);`

where in Configuration class DBConn string contains connection string to sql ie:

`Data Source=XYZ\\DEV;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=600;connection lifetime=600`

`Integrated Security=True` tells that you want to use windows auth.