# I can't set up a connection string for ASP.Net MVC v4.0 with standard method of Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection, connection-string, vpn

Please I need help with this scenario:

I want to use the default ASP Membership/Authentication in my MVC app, connected to a VPN.
In web.config I setup the connection "MyCustomConnection":

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
    <add name="MyCustomConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.x.x.y\somewhere;Initial Catalog=The.Main.DB;User ID=sa;Password=sapass;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` I have:

```
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyCustomConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the debugger hit(After a click in the Login Hyperlink of the Basic Template) `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyCustomConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true)`, threw an exception:

```
Cannot open database "The.Main.DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'VPN\MYUSER'.
```

Additionally in User Context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("MyCustomConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

My question is:

Why `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyCustomConnection",...` is trying to connect with the user of vpn and no with 'sa'(and his password 'sapass') as my connection string.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "connecting via VPN" have to do with ASP.NET membership?

Comment: Maybe because `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("connectionstringname"...` is taken as Id the User of the VPN, and no the Id of the 'connectionstringname'.

Comment: do you have a setting for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the connection string, specifically the use of `Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI` for more information, check here: [Difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi)