# Invalid Object Name from LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, visual-web-developer

I have an SQL Server database and I have just added a new table:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[my_table](
    [my_primary_key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [my_data_value] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [my_primary_key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I drag the new table from the Database Explorer in Visual Web Developer into the `my_schema.dbml` design window. This creates for me a `my_schema.vb` file thus:-

```
Partial Class my_schemaDataContext

End Class
```

although some trace of the table does appear in the XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Database Name="my_schema" Class="my_schemaDataContext" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
  <Connection Mode="AppSettings" ConnectionString="Data Source=MYPC;Initial Catalog=my_schema;Integrated Security=True" SettingsObjectName="MyProgram.My.MySettings" SettingsPropertyName="my_schemaConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <Table Name="dbo.my_table" Member="my_tables">
    <Type Name="my_table">
      <Column Name="my_primary_key" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="my_data_value" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

I then try to insert rows into the table like this:-

```
Try
    db = New my_schemaDataContext("Integrated Security=SSPI; ")
    Dim new_row As my_table
    new_row = New my_table
    new_row.my_primary_key = 1
    new_row.my_data_value = 1
    db.my_tables.InsertOnSubmit(new_row)
    db.SubmitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
    ' do something
End Try
```

This results in an exception `Invalid Object Name 'dbo.my_table`.

Presumably I have to jam the schema name in somewhere but can't see how to do this. I tried adding `Initial Catalogue=my_schema;` to the connection string but this resulted in an exception `Keyword Not Supported: Initial Catalogue`.

Has anyone any idea what else I could try? (I should note that I have also tried other tables in the same schema with the same results, which I hope would eliminate the possibility of random typos causing the problem.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the connection string is incorrect. Also I believe `Catalogue` should be spelt at `Catalog`.

Comment: Groan. That's it. Correcting `Catalogue` to `Catalog` fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your DataContext takes a connection string.

```
"Integrated Security=SSPI; "
```

doesn't look like a valid connection string to me.

If you give nothing, it will take the connection string set at the creation. Here it is the setting `my_schemaConnectionString`. So just do:

```
db = New my_schemaDataContext()
```

Or if you want to change it at runtime:

```
string connectionString = "whatever";
db = New my_schemaDataContext(connectionString)
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1229745/206725) will explain all about the `Integrated Security=` part