# Asp .net Web config file connection string with secured

Tags: asp.net, web-config, config, asp.net-3.5

I have following connection string in my web application.

```
<add name="ApplicationDs" connectionString="Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=XXX;Password=xxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

For some security purpose , unable to put **sql username** and **password** directly in **web.config** file. If anything build in security option is available in asp .net to handle this.

Advice me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integrated security and run your web application with a user account you gave permissions to within your database.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

for more connection string examples, find them here
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: Thanks.. Hi could you explain about Integrated Security=SSPI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi

Answer (score 1):

You might consider encrypting your connection string section. If the security issue is that the username and password cannot be exposed in clear text, then encryption might help/solve the issue.

For more information on web.config encryption, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link.