# Cannot open database in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am following this tutorial

http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2013/05/part-8-data-access-in-mvc-using-entity.html

but I got this error upon completing

[image]

I tried to change this connection in the tutorial

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext" 
        connectionString="server=.; database=MVCDemo; integrated security=SSPI"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

to:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
          connectionString="Data Source=RL-PC\INSTANCE1;Initial Catalog=MVCDemo;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you an admin on the computer?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi

Comment: Yes. I used that connection string in my winforms application and it is working. I guess connection string is different when it comes to MVC.

Comment: Are you using MS-SQL? SQL express?

Answer (score 0):

When testing this locally, change your connection string to the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCDemo;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

if your instance is SQLEXPRESS, otherwise replace that with the appropriate instance. Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you getting the same error? If you have the full version of SQL and not SQLEXPRESS, put your instance name instead of SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

Open SQL Management Studio then Goto

- **SECURITY**-->**LOGIN**--> right click on--> **RL-PC\RL**
- select -->**PROPTERY**
- select **USER MAPPING**
- **CHECKED** your project **database** then
- CHECKED--> **db owner**
- CHECKED--> **db securityadmin**
- CHECKED--> **public**
- Click Ok and Run your project .hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Open SQL Management Studio
And When The Login Box Shows, Copy That Server Name
And Paste It Instead Of

```
RL-PC\INSTANCE1
```