# Connect to MSSQL using a specific Windows account while the application uses different credentials

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I've got an application which is running under under the credentials of the local user. However, I would like to allow this application access to a MSSQL database using specific credentials.

This isn't a problem if I use an SQL login, however I would like to use a specific Windows account for which I have the username (along with the domain) and password. Note that I do NOT wish to run the entire application using these credentials.

Is this at all possible? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi) seems to suggest that using `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string WITH Windows credentials specified will allow me to login to the database as that user, however I was not able to do this on my test machine.

<sub>Given how the SQL Server Management Studio logs into databases (i.e. it uses the current credentials or specified SQL credentials, but doesn't seem to permit specified Windows credentials) I'm thinking this cannot be done, but I would like a confirmation of this...</sub>

Comment: This can only be done if you can impersonate your app, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net

Answer (score 1):

You could deal with this as the SQL Server end

by encapsulating the tasks that need done under the other account in a stored procedure created using the "EXECUTE AS Clause"

```
Create Proc sp_Dosomething_As_specific_user
WITH EXECUTE AS '{SpecificUser}'
BEGIN
 /*Do Something*/
END
```

and allow the user account execute permissions on that

```
GRANT EXEC ON sp_Dosomething_As_specific_user TO {Actual_User}
```

For fuller details on the "EXECUTE AS" clause look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx

This means that you've limited the user to running only a specifically predefined action or set of actions as the other user as opposed to a general permission to let them impersonate the other user

Which is going to help keep whoever is responsible for IT security happy

Comment: An interesting answer, but given that this is a client-side problem and that I cannot really change the database to such extents this isn't the solution I'm looking for.