# Update-Database caused an exception while creating a New Database using code first in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I currently try to move to asp.net core using visual studio 2017. 
I tried to implement the tutorial provided by Microsoft ([ASP.NET Core - New database with Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)).
I did all the steps but during the Creating Database step, I got an error.
I successfully created the migration file using Add-Migration command in PMC. But, Using the command "Update-Database" raise an exception.
The exception is:

> PM> Update-Database System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation
>   resulted in an overflow.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO&
>   pClientConsumerInfo, IntPtr& ppConn)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncEx(ConsumerInfo
>   consumerInfo, String constring, IntPtr& pConn, Byte[] spnBuffer,
>   Byte[] instanceName, Boolean fOverrideCache, Boolean fSync, Int32
>   timeout, Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNIHandle..ctor(ConsumerInfo myInfo, String
>   serverName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int32
>   timeout, Byte[]& instanceName, Boolean flushCache, Boolean fSync,
>   Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String
>   serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]&
>   instanceName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async,
>   Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout,
>   Boolean withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0(DateTime
>   giveUp)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2
>   operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy
>   strategy, Func`2 operation, TState state)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

any suggestion please

Comment: Did you check this problem on an other computer? Do some investigation if this issue is already known on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues)

Comment: I did code first in VS 2015 without such problem on this computer. and also can create database and new connection in VS 2017.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I found the answer in this URL:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jeroen, 
I just copy the answer here to help you navigate less.

> The problem is caused by Lavasoft:
>
> 1- In Service.msc, Stop the LavasoftTcpService.
>   2- In Program and Features, uninstalled WebCompanion.
>   3- Go to "C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64)", Rename LavasoftTcpService.dll and LavasoftTcpService64.dll
>
> *> If you try to rename the dlls before the 1st and 2nd steps the problem resolve
>   localhost: instead of 127.0.0.1 system was looking for 0.0.0.0. Ping
>   and you will recieve an error message "Ping request could not find host
>   localhost. Please check the name and try again".*

I found the answer in this URL:   [Arithmetic overflow exception when opening SQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609088/arithmetic-overflow-exception-when-opening-sql-connection)  .