# authentication windows sql connection

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to set up a website where I want the person viewing to be authenticated using windows authentication mode. However in connecting to the sql server database I want to use a windows service account.

Can anyone help? Basically either I can connect to the database but the windows user is then not pulling through or windows auth works but the datbase connection is saying the user is anonymous.

Comment: post some code and actual error messages. missing technical details isn't possible to help you.

Comment: <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="true" />
 </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PerformContext" connectionString="Server=OVOIO-SPSQL;Database=PerformDB;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

So I want the user to connect to the application as a windows account but I want the application to connect to the database with a specific AD service account

Comment: please edit your post, add details and explanation there. there you can format text and expand your request in a better and comprehensible manner.

Comment: Mike, what is your problem? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi it explains the use of user/password in connection String