# How to set username and password in connection string for connecting to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is my first asp web site and I published the project for web , but now the page with db connection do not work properly , I am sure about user and password what else should I do ?!!
this is connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbnameConnectionString" connectionString="server=.;database=dbname;uid=user;password=pass;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and this s a error that i get :
Login failed for user 'WIN-J9A67LA4GER\hostusername_web'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'WIN-J9A67LA4GER\hostusername_web'.

Source Error: 
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'WIN-J9A67LA4GER\hostusername_web'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352431
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +891
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +43
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +41
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +21
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +33
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Lessons.InitialUI() +474
   Lessons.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +338
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: Is your server located at "."? Because that's what your connectionstring says.

Comment: if its a sql express installation you got you need to specify server=.\sqlexpress

Comment: it would be really useful if any one who vote me down tell me why ?!!!!!

Comment: guys database is at "." and it is not sql express its sql server , the problem wast Integrated security property , u can find the answer above .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem is right there in the stack.

```
Login failed for user 'WIN-J9A67LA4GER\hostusername_web'
```

You are setting `Integrated Security=True` and also specifying a username and password. From my understanding `Integrated Security=True` will use the Windows Credentials that the website is running under. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-security-sspi).

If you want to specify a SQL Login in your connection string then you need to set that to False.

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string specifying `Integrated Security=True` which means the connection will use the current window credentials.

So if you want to use the `username` and `password` provided by you in connection string then set this property to `false`.

```
<add name="dbnameConnectionString" connectionString="server=.;database=dbname;uid=user;password=pass;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security= false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```