# Connection String login fail "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON"

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have Stored Procedure in SQL that works in C# fine locally. When I publish my C# project and call that stored procedure, it do not work anymore.

My Connection String:

```
<add name="SqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=BD;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Calling the Stored Procedure:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = null;
String SqlconString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(SqlconString))
{
  sqlCon.Open();
  SqlCommand sql_cmnd = new SqlCommand("Actualizar_Avaliacoes_Servicos", sqlCon);
  sql_cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sql_cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  sqlCon.Close();
}
```

[image: Error Fail Login]

Comment: Use Sql Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication, by setting "Integrated Security=false; User Id=[user_name];Password=[pass]" into connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a web application does not have rights to connect to the database.  You will need to do one of 2 things.

1. Change your connection string to store the username and password. [How to set username and password in connection string for connecting to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791379/how-to-set-username-and-password-in-connection-string-for-connecting-to-database)
2. Launch IIS Manager and change the settings for the application's pool so it
   runs as a user with database rights. [Add IIS 7 AppPool Identities as SQL Server Logons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933134/add-iis-7-apppool-identities-as-sql-server-logons)