# How to connect SQL Server on Cloud Virtual Machine to Web App in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, cloud

I am having a problem on connecting my web application on the cloud server. My application works perfectly on the Test Server (On-Prem) using this connection string

`<connectionStrings> <add name="CONNECTIONNAME" providerName="MSOLEDBSQL" connectionString="Data Source=IPADDRESS; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; UID=USERNAME; PWD=PASSWORD; Connection Timeout=100000; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" /> </connectionStrings>`

But when I use this connection string and change the `Data Source`, `Initial Catalog` to the Cloud Server information, Remove the `UID and PWD` because it has no authorization, It returned Object Reference is not set meaning the connection I am linking is incorrect.

Am I doing something wrong or what? Can someone help me solve my problem.

I already tried setting the `Data Source` to `localhost` and there is no improvement. I put already the `Trusted Connection` because there is no `USERNAME and PASSWORD` on SQL Server, I am only using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Where is your database server located? Inside the VM?

Comment: @CharlesHan, Yes Sir.

Comment: Can you log in to the database server inside the VM using SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below connection string,

```
<connectionStrings> 
 <add name="CONNECTIONNAME" 
   connectionString="data source=localhost;
   initial catalog=<DBNAME>;
   Integrated Security=SSPI;
   Connection Timeout=100000;
   Trusted_Connection=True;
   MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What the. Thank you, Sir. That will do. So setting the Integrated Security Fix the problem, How is that? Tried removing it and it will not work. Can you explain more? Thanks again Sir. A lot.

Comment: Setting the `Integrated Security` field to True or SSPI means you want to log in to the database via Windows Authentication. A bit more explanation from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/what-is-the-difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-securit