# Connect to SQL Server with JS

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I stumbled across a post on here regarding connecting to a DB with JavaScript.

[How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript)

I'm building a gadget for windows vista/7 that will work with My Movies, a movie management app for Media Centre. The My Movies app uses SQL Server 2005 Express for its DB, and the only option I have for DB connectivity is JavaScript as gadgets do not (to my knowledge) support server side scripting languages.

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=WKS-MER03308;Initial Catalog=MYMOVIES;User ID=mymovies;Password=7eBrABud;Provider=SQLOLEDB"; 

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT nvcLocalTitle FROM tblTitles", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

I've tried running this and I continue getting the error:

> Message: Login failed for user 'mymovies'. (Unfortunately I can't access the logs to see the state and get an accurate reason for the failure)

On the my movies website it gives the following details for connecting to the db.

```
Server=[Server]\MYMOVIES
Database=My Movies
User ID=mymovies
Password=7eBrABud
Trusted_Connection=False
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the instance and database name confused.  Try the following:

```
var connectionstring="Data Source=WKS-MER03308\MYMOVIES;Initial Catalog=MY MOVIES;
     User ID=mymovies;Password=7eBrABud;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
```

Comment: I've tried that and it's got rid of the issue but I now get this:

Message: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Line: 12
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Development/Sourcecode/TestingSite/JSSQLTest.html