# Connecting to a remote Microsoft SQL server from Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a way to connect to a Microsoft SQL database from Node.js. I'm aware of the MySQL drivers, but I have data that I need to pull from a MS SQL database and would rather pull directly from Node.js rather than hack a PHP script of some sort in place.

Comment: Were you finally able to accomplish this without building the proxy or using ActiveX?

Comment: I'm kind of glad I just came across this because I was wondering if anybody would be interested in my node.js-mssql project. 

It's highly rudimentary at the moment, but I'll be doing another big push later this week with more functionality :)
https://github.com/orenmazor/node-tds

Comment: A pure javascript solution provides the node.js module [tds4node](https://npmjs.org/package/tds4node). GitHub link: [tds](https://github.com/ttghr/tds)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js and Microsoft SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156806/node-js-and-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to wrap your SQL Server with a JSON outputting web-service.  On the positive side, it should be relatively easy to do.

Be nice if the JavaScript engine in node.js could do this: (from [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript/857688#857688)):

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Comment: Should I downvote this answer, because this is not the best answer anymore in 2014? I'm not sure if downvoting an obsolete answer is considered morally permissible. Look here for the what I think should be used today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156806/node-js-and-microsoft-sql-server/22658512#22658512

Comment: This is no longer a good answer in 2015. [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) (if you want ORM) or [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) are much better options.

Answer (score 10):

Check out a new option:

https://github.com/orenmazor/node-tds

(from [Node.js and Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156806/node-js-and-microsoft-sql-server/5156855#5156855))

Comment: The node-tds project description now reads `*EXPERIMENTAL and currently ABANDONED*`

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend [node-mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql), which is a nice wrapper for other connectors, the default being my previous choice ([Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious)) bringing a bit nicer of an interface.  This is a JavaScript implimentation, with no compilation requirements, meaning you can work in windows and non-windows environments alike.

Another option, if you don't mind bringing in .Net or Mono with a binary bridge would be to use [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/).  Which can be very nice if you want to leverage .Net libraries in node.js

[node-tds](https://github.com/orenmazor/node-tds) is abandoned, [node-odbc](https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc) doesn't work with windows, and the MS [node-sqlserver](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver) driver doesn't seem to work on non-windows (and has some goofy requirements).

Answer (score 4):

If you are connecting to Mssql from linux you can use node-odbc ( https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc ) with the freetds odbc driver. I am using this in production and its faster than wrapping a web service.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, from Microsoft even,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995

Or a linux sql client driver via odbc:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160

Comment: The MS option requires a binary module build, and appears to be windows only.

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do this.  the microsoft driver is just one.  I actually don't use it though for the same reason, windows only. :(  I've just found this today though... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160

Answer (score 2):

New answer for 2015: The ORM package [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) now supports MS SQL, using the [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) driver under the covers.

This is the best way I've found to interact with Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem, I was trying to connect the MSSQL that is hosted on a remote server. The config that I had to use is-

```
let config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'database',
    "options":{
        instanceName: 'instanceName',
        "encrypt":true,
        "enableArithAbort":true,
        "trustServerCertificate": true,
       }
};
module.exports=config;
```

For getting the instance name use SELECT @@servicename in SSMS