# Changing the location of index.js in Yeoman, ExpressJS and Socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, express, yeoman

I am trying to merge a working Socket.io, AngularJS and ExpressJS 3.x project into the new Yeoman: Express Stack.

I started by following the directions given on https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack, 
namely,

yeomen init angularcrud            # Standard Angular app

yeomen init angularcrud:crud post  # Angular CRUD routes/views

yeomen init express post           # Express CRUD

yeomen server

I have merged the codes carefuly checking that at each point the new code works. This process is sucessful until I add socket.io. At that point, when I run "yeoman server", I get the error "/socket.io/socket.io.js Not Found" which is substantially similar to the error in the following question [Socket.io not being served by Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625373/socket-io-not-being-served-by-node-js-server). In First Zero's answer to the question, he states that "node_modules should be in the same directory as server.js, not above server root". In the directory set-up that Yeoman: Express Stack creates, this is exactly the situation, node_modules is one level above the server root (index.js). If one simply moves index.js to the same level as node_modules, one gets a cannot find module error.

I would like to know how to modify the set-up to get Yeoman: Express working with socket-io.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing this branch a bit the last few days though not with socket.io
class I know this much that node_modules goes in the project root not in server/

You may need to either install socket.io via npm as a global or put ../ before before 
your require('../socket.io') or something. Also we do what most Express/Angular stubs/seeds/examples have too which is to include a wildcard route at the end of Express 
route definitions.

If you also need a catchall route and/or set html5mode to true
then you need to make sure you define it like below or angular spirals 
your client session into a self-referencing loading loop:

```
app.get(/^((?!\/styles|scripts\/).)*$/, function(req, res){
  res.render('<app_path>/app/index.html'); // or chrome.html if you call it such
```

});

Hope that helps somewhat

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for your module issue try going into /yeoman-custom dir and installing it there as that is the actual root that yeoman-custom/cli/tasks/server.js serves up with Node.