# node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i keep on getting the error 
/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

my code is

```
var express = require('express'), http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);
```

and

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

what is the problem ???

any help is welcome!

Comment: Are you serving your HTML files from the same Node app as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.io not being served by Node.js server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625373/socket-io-not-being-served-by-node-js-server)

Comment: @robertklep: ah no, i have an index.html page... From the app.js I get info: socket.io started

Comment: @Bondye nope, that's not the issue here

Comment: @hausinho if your HTML is being served by a different server you need to include the full URL to the socket.io file: `<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` (or some other hostname, obviously)

Comment: @robertklep ok tried that, no effect, same error :-/

Comment: @hausinho works for me with the code you're showing, it's serving the .js file properly. Check your browsers console.

Comment: @robertklep ok there must be something wrong with my installation? i run xampp... localhost/htdocs/project/chat/ - installed everything in the chat folder... ther node_modules folder also exists...

Comment: @hausinho ideally, the Node server that's running the chat application should also serve the `socket.io.js` file, that how it commonly works. I'm assuming that you actually have a Node app running?

Comment: @robertklep I assume i do :-) did run "node app.js" from the command prompt and got the socket.io started message, but thats maybe not what it means to run a node app?

Comment: @hausinho that looks fine :)

Comment: @robertklep ok good! but still i dont get why its not working.. even when i enter localhost:3000/project/chat/socket.io/socket.io.js i get the Object not found error page... running out of ideas now

Comment: @hausinho it should be `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`, try that.

Comment: ah yes sorry, that was what i (also) tried, but no luck...

Comment: @hausinho sorry, I give up :(

Comment: @robertklep no prob! me too! thx for you help anyways! :-)

Answer (score 85):

Copying `socket.io.js` to a public folder (something as `resources/js/socket.io.js`) is not the proper way to do it.

If `Socket.io` server listens properly to your `HTTP` server, it will automatically serve the client file to via `http://localhost:<port>/socket.io/socket.io.js`, you don't need to find it or copy in a publicly accessible folder as `resources/js/socket.io.js` & serve it manually.

**Code sample** 
[Express 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) -
Express 3 requires that you instantiate a `http.Server` to attach `socket.io` to first

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');
//make sure you keep this order
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//... 

server.listen(8000);
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This should be the validated answer for this socket.io issue. Thanks!

Comment: I had similar problem which was related to the fact that I was refactoring old code, which was using `app.listen(3000);`. This was not working. When I've changed it to `server.listen(3000);` it starts working fine.

Comment: I'd suggest that the index.html which calls '  var socket = io('http://localhost);' is also updated to use the correct port

Comment: ah! You inject the server into the listen method. Thanks!

Comment: @edufinn gosh. You nailed it man, the problem was exactly that. Thank you

Comment: what would the client code look like though?

Answer (score 13):

How to find socket.io.js for client side

install socket.io

```
npm install socket.io
```

find socket.io client

```
find ./ | grep client | grep socket.io.js
```

result:

```
./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
```

copy socket.io.js to your resources:

```
cp ./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js /home/proyects/example/resources/js/
```

in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok copied the socket.io.js into a folder which i called js so now its <script src="js/socket.io.js"></script> - but now i get the error http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1382087281918 !?!?!?

Comment: this is not the error, this is the connection request, you must create the events in your server/client to comunicate with

Comment: +1, searched for some hours before I finally found this source that there is a socket.io.js that may be copied into the lib

Comment: This is useful solution when using just client without server

Answer (score 9):

It seems that this question may have never been answered (although it may be too late for the OP, I'll answer it for anyone who comes across it in the future and needs to solve the problem).

Instead of doing `npm install socket.io` you have to do `npm install socket.io --save` so the socket.io module gets installed in your web development folder (run this command at the base location/where your index.html or index.php is). This installs socket.io to the area in which the command is run, not globally, and, in addition, it automatically corrects/updates your package.json file so node.js knows that it is there.

Then change your source path from `'/socket.io/socket.io.js'` to `'http://' + location.hostname + ':3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'`.

Answer (score 3):

... "You might be wondering where the /socket.io/socket.io.js file
comes from, since we neither add it and nor does it exist on the filesystem. This is
part of the magic done by io.listen on the server. It creates a handler on the server
to serve the socket.io.js script file."

from the book Socket.IO Real-time Web
Application Development, page 56

Comment: This is not enought to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must just follow https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and all will work.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the socket.io tutorial https://socket.io/get-started/chat/, you should add this line as below.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')))
```

This is because in the tutorial, **Express** will only catch the url 
`/` and send the file of `index.html`.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

However, in the `index.html`, you have a script tag (`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`) requests the resouce of `socket.io-client`, which is not routed in `index.js` (it can be found in console-network that the url is `http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the directory path mentioned in your code.By default it is  `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');`

make sure you index.html in proper directory

Answer (score 1):

Steps to debug

1. `npm install socket.io --save` in static files (index.html) for example, you may have installed it globally and when you look at the debugger, the file path is empty.
2. Change your script file and instantiate the socket explicitly adding your localhost that you have set up in your server file

   ```
    <script src="http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
          const socket = io.connect("localhost:5000");
           $(() =>
   ```

   Double check that the data is flowing by opening a new browser tab and pasting `http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js` you should see the socket.io.js data
3. Double check that your server has been set-up correctly and if you get a CORs error  `npm install cors` then add it to the `server.js` (or index.js whatever you have chosen to name your server file)

   ```
    const cors = require("cors");
    const http = require("http").Server(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(http);
   ```

   Then use the Express middleware `app.use()` method to instantiate cors. Place the middleware this above your connection to your static root file

   ```
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
   ```
4. As a final check make sure your server is connected with the `http.listen()` method where you are assigning your port, the first arg is your port number, for example I have used 5000 here.

   ```
    const server = http.listen(5000, () => {
      console.log("your-app listening on port", server.address().port);
    });
   ```
5. As your `io.on()` method is working, and your sockets data is connected client-side, add your `io.emit()` method with the callback logic you need and in the front-end JavaScript files use the `socket.on()` method again with the call back logic you require. Check that the data is flowing.

I have also edited a comment above as it was the most useful to me - but I had some additional steps to take to make the client-server connection work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually download "socket.io/socket.io.js" file and attaché to html (and not want to get from server runtime) you can use https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha512-eVL5Lb9al9FzgR63gDs1MxcDS2wFu3loYAgjIH0+Hg38tCS8Ag62dwKyH+wzDb+QauDpEZjXbMn11blw8cbTJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

while this doesn't have anything to do with the OP, if you're running across this issue while maintaining someone else's code, you might find that the problem is caused by the coder setting `io.set('resource', '/api/socket.io');` in the application script, in which case your HTML code would be `<script>type="text/javascript" src="/api/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

If this comes during development. Then one of the reasons could be you are running a client-side file(index.html). But what you should do is run your server(example at localhost:3000) and let the server handle that static file(index.html). In this way, the socket.io package will automatically make
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`  available on the client side.

Illustration(FileName: index.js):

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const port = 3001 || process.env.PORT;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

//MiddleWares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
console.log('New user joined');
}
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App has been started at port ${port}`);
});
```

After this run your server file by the command
`node index.js`
Then open the `localhost:${port}`, Replace port with given in the index.js file and run it. 
It solved my problem. Hope it solves yours too.