# Node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found express 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

So I'm trying to get chat working on my website, and when I was testing locally it worked great, because port 8080 on my localhost was available and all that good stuff. But now I pushed my code to my Heroku app, and when I try and load my chat page, I get the error stating that it can't get localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js.

I've seen [node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426882/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found)
and tried the suggestions, but none worked, even moving the socket.io.js file into a resource file did not work. I'm guessing this is because I'm using express 4.0?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Edit:
So to add more details, since my question could seem a little vague, here is my relevant app.js code:

```
 var client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
```

In my jade file for the chat page, I have:

```
 script (src = `'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`')
```

and later on

```
 var socket = io.connect(`'http://localhost:8080`');
```

and all this works on localhost (I load up on port 5000, socket.io is connected to port 8080). I do this using 'foreman start' with the heroku toolbelt.

When I try and change these to work on heroku, it breaks and I'm not sure how to fix it. I hope this clarifies the question a bit.

Edit 2:
I'm running:
express 4.0.0

socket.io 0.9.16

node 0.10.x

Thanks

Comment: can u post the error message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have an explicit route in `express` which catches all other routes? Something like this perhaps:

```
app.get("/", handlers.home);
app.get("/..." ...);
...
app.get("*", handlers.error);
```

This might keep `socket.io` from being able to host it's own js file for the client. There is an easy way to fix this, since you probably already have a `public` or `static` folder setup in express. Something like:

> app.use(express.static("public"));

Make a new folder called `socket.io` and copy over the appropriate `socket.io.js` file into said folder, and all should be well. **However note that there are two files named `socket.io.js`!!** So, if you see something like `"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"` it means you copied the "node-ey" server side file. Here is the correct **client** file to copy:

> app_dir/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js

**Note @BHendricks:** I would have just posted as a reply to your comment, but I currently lack the required reputation.

**Edit**:
The OPs question probably has more to do with the "localhost" issue. When connecting from a client (say your home IP), as far as your browser knows - localhost implies a connection with the machine which is locally hosting stuff. Since your home machine (or phone) does not host socket.io, this is failing.

What you need to do is have your server embed the socket connection information (either a fully qualified hostname, ip etc). This can be done when the server "renders" the page with the client connection.

Comment: I copied the js files into the public folder (after creating the socket.io directory inside that), then getting the below error when I use let socket = io("http://localhost:5000"); in FrontEnd. Can some one please help

GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nnpj-9M 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you go to `http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`?

Does it 404? If it does you need to make sure you have it in a directory that Express is set to serve statically.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then put your `socket.io.js` file in `public/socket.io/socket.io.js` (relative to your app.js file)

Restart your server and see if that fixes it.

Basically, Express doesn't serve files statically from the file system unless you explicitly tell it where to map from.

Comment: I tried this approach, and I changed my script line script (src = `'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`') to (src = `'/socket.io/socket.io.js`') and now I get : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Thank you! This works great. If you are minifying / uglifying your client side JS etc too, this provides a way to opt out of that. Much appreciated.