# Heroku socket.io sample error in Express 4.0

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, express, socket.io

So I'm trying to use the sample heroku application: https://github.com/lstoll/socket-io-chat-heroku  as a template to build my own socket.io application, but I'm running on Express 4.0, Node 0.10.x, and Socket.io 0.9.16.

Now the problem is that when I run my server, everything is fine, but when I run my client, I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined socket.io.js:12
 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined chat2:2
```

My relevant server code is as follows:

```
 var app = express();
 var http = require('http');
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var sio = require('socket.io');
 var port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

 server.listen(port);
 var io = sio.listen(server);

 io.sockets.on('connection'), function(socket) {
   ...
 });
```

On my client side, I have the following:
I've tried both (this is in jade, by the way):

```
  script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js') OR script(src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js')
  var socket = io.connect() OR var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000')
```

Neither of these options have worked, always resulting in an error on the client side. 
Is there something special to do for Express 4.0? I've asked a very similar question here: [Node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found express 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179827/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found-express-4-0) but this is another attempt at getting chat to work with a different template.

Update and Edit: after some work, I was able to deploy a heroku app using express 4.0 and socket.io, at: http://salty-escarpment-7398.herokuapp.com/chat.

The problem now is to integrate it back into my current app, and after much work, I now am getting an error:

```
 22:19:56 web.1  | GET /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 404 26ms - 1.67kb
 22:19:59 web.1  | GET /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 404 25ms - 1.67kb
```

I have:

```
 io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
 io.set('polling duration', 10);
```

To set it to xhr-polling, and my server code is pretty much identical to what was above. The page loads, though, and it's only when trying to send a chat that nothing happens and the 404 starts appearing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for the 404 errors with `/socket.io/?EIO=2...`?

Answer (score 0):

By default Socket.IO 1.0.4 allows polling and websocket transports. You removed polling transport ! return the polling transport back:

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 
                  'flashsocket', 
                  'htmlfile', 
                  'xhr-polling', 
                  'jsonp-polling', 
                  'polling']);
```