# Uncaught reference error require is not defined

Tags: node.js, symfony

I'm trying to use an html page in order to test the connection with my server.

I've got no problem with my server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");
// Chargement de socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);



var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    // Quand un client se connecte, on le note dans la console


});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Un client est connecté !');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

My client should is an html page here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Socket.io</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Communication test with socket.io !</h1>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/server_node/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem is, when I load the html client, I've got this error

> > socket.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> >         at socket.js:6

I'm not trying to implement a real client, I just want a simple page in order to do some connection test.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Problem fixed, it was all because I wasn't loading the html file from the serverlike this `fs.readFile('./ClientTest.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {`

As this is just used to do some test, it's fine if it works this way; the client side will be with an other platform.

Sorry for that useless issue :(

Comment: <script src="http://localhost:8080/server_node/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js"></script>

Comment: The port number is 8080 and not 8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be importing the *server-side* library on the client, you want to be importing the [client-side](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) one.

As per the docs, this is automatically served when socket.io runs on the server which you can import via

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" />
```

Comment: I tried this already, but then I've got this one >>  GET file:///socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @Minirock have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25527751/10429036)?

Comment: @OliverNybo Yesbut still it's not working.Thing is there is no socket.io.js file in the socket.io folder.

Comment: And did you do `npm instsall socket.io --save`? The **--save** is important.

Comment: @Minirock that would suggest to me that you are running this locally (i.e. you are not serving the HTML via the Node server). Have you tried `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js` in that case?