# How to install node.js modules downloaded manually

Tags: node.js, npm

I know this question has been asked many times over, but I haven't been able to find a question that describes my exact situation. I installed node 0.10.18 on Windows 7, and managed to find a lot of modules downloaded manually, now the problem is how to install these modules. For example i wish to install socket.io, i have it, as well as all the dependencies, as separate folders. What cache/install options I need to tweak to allow local installation of this module and its dependencies? I do not have access to an Internet connection so I cannot use npm like its meant to be used...

Comment: Why not just get `npm` working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300132/how-to-use-npm-with-node-exe

Comment: @remus, I am sorry, I believe my first sentence should have been I do not have access to an Internet connection, at least not enough to install all these modules, my University downloads these modules and puts them on the local FTP to use them in a manner I am now trying to figure out

Comment: You can still use NPM to install local packages - if you can get the NPM package installed, then use [`npm install ftp://<path>`](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html)

Comment: What about search for dependencies, will it look them up in that same path? I ask you because i can't try it right now

Comment: @remus you can also do `npm install /local/path`

Comment: You might be able to just copy the modules already downloaded to a node_modules folder inside your app. If the module was properly downloaded it will have all its dependencies as subfolders