# How to setup Node.js and Npm behind a corporate web proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

How can I configure `node.js` and `npm` to run behind a web proxy?

I tried the following solutions but they didn't work for me.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

and

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Answer (score 5):

First open a command console at the location of your `npm` installation.

Then you can configure your npm to use a proxy using the commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://{url}:{port}
npm config set https-proxy http://{url}:{port}
```

Notice the protocol is set to `http` for both the `proxy` and `https-proxy` variables.

If you would like `npm` to store your credentials for the proxy, 
you can additionally modify the commands as follows:

```
npm config set proxy http://{username}:{passphrase}@{url}:{port}
npm config set https-proxy http://{username}:{passphrase}@{url}:{port}
```

For example:

```
npm config set proxy http://LanguidSquid:Password1@my.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://LanguidSquid:Password1@my.company.com:8080
```

Additional information here: [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Comment: npm is broke  after seting proxy. I am using `node-v6.11.2-linux-x64` version.

Exception log:
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at Url.parse (url.js:269:19)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:75:5)
    at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (/app/phoenix/node-v6.11.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:164:13)

please advise @Blake

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me!

1. npm config set strict-ssl false
2. npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
3. npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
4. npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port

NOTE:
Remember to add **https://** instead of **http://** when **setting registry**

Hope that helps.

Comment: `npm config set strict-ssl false` is doing the trick when behind a proxy PAC, but it is a bit dirty... why NPM can't use the proxy PAC settings ?