# angular2 quickstart npm install fails

Tags: node.js, angular, exitstatus

I get the following error when I try to run- npm install. error as below:

```css
npm ERR! node v0.12.12
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings ins
tall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: did you create the `typings` file?  Was only "recently" added to quick start.

Comment: I did create it ..typings.json

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the quickstart (manually typed and also from the git repo).  I have node 4.4.2 and typings 0.7.12 installed.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you have `typings` package installed.

`npm install -g typings`

Also make sure you have `typings.json` file available.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), from the Angular2 team.

Comment: I tried the same and still the same error. I am following the same tutorial

Comment: You are running a very old version of node. The current is v4.4.1. Try updating your nodejs.

Comment: Try adding empty json to typings.json like  so : `{ }`

Answer (score 4):

Not the same error, but I had a proxy issue that was causing `typings install` to fail: if you had a proxy issue for `npm` then you will have a proxy issue for `typings` too.

The error I was getting is:

```
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/selenium-webdriver/tags/2.44.0%2B20160317120654"
typings ERR! caused by connect ECONNREFUSED 104.24.112.177:443
```

I fixed this by creating a settings file for `typings` in my `%HOMEPATH%` folder:

**%HOMEPATH%\.typingsrc**

```
proxy=http://DOMAIN%5Cusername:password@proxy:port/
https-proxy=http://DOMAIN%5Cusername:password@proxy:port/
rejectUnauthorized=false
```

See these links for more details: the first one suggests putting the `.typingsrc` file in your project folder, but you can use the home folder like `npm`.

- https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/106
- [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Comment: Upvoted. Not sure about the HOMEPATH but the root of the folder also does it.

Answer (score 0):

I am behind corporate proxy, 
I just tried with creating a file .typingsrc with the below content and placed in the root folder of my application

```
{
"proxy":"http://proxy-server:8080",
"rejectUnauthorized": false
}
```

It worked finally..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not-too-old npm version. You can see how to upgrade [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions).

After you have a new npm version, install the typings package:

```
npm install -g typings
```