# How to install anything using npm install under a proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to use the following tutorial to learn ReactJS: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

I'm on a corporate network, so I'm under a proxy, hence I cannot install anything using npm install.. I need to do the following: `npm install -g babel; npm install -g babel-cli; npm install webpack --save; npm install webpack-dev-server --save; npm install react --save` etc.. So, how do I do that under a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

These are plenty of examples to use npm with proxy. You may want to take a look of these:

- [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)
- https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Generally, you can just run those commands to use an HTTP proxy:

```sh
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Else, if you are using Mac and want to use SocksV5 proxy, this is your command (Source: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6204):

```sh
ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:5000 npm install anypackage -g
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but it is not working for me. Still giving me ETIMEDOUT error.

Comment: What's the type of proxy you used?

Comment: Looks like HTTP proxy. the `npm config set proxy` should work. Have you tried it too?