# Unable to install npm under corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, babeljs

I have tried everything given in this link:

[Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

But I'm still unable to install webpack and babel.

I've been told that if I got npm from nodejs, then I need to modify my path to avoid using that one. The npm by default will go to `C:\Users\username\xxxx`. So, I updated the path as: `%PATH%;C:\Users\username\xxxx;C:\util\nodejs`. But I just have an empty npm folder under the path C:\Users\username\xxx & still, it's reading the npm from the nodejs one only.

Even `npm install npm -g` is also not working (same proxy error).

Answer (score 0):

Set proxy using : 
npm config set https-proxy http://your_proxy_ip:port

Check 
npm config list or npm config get registry

if it returns: 
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

then run command: 
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Now try running:
npm install

and then run:
npm start

It should work.