# npm failing to encode %5C

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I am trying to connect to npm from behind a proxy that uses a domain. I am trying to implement the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac) question.

```
npm config set proxy "http://domain%5Cusername:password@servername:port/"
```

However, when I try this, it ends up turning the string into:

```
http://domain/%5Cusername:password@servername:port/
```

Note the "/" between "domain" and "%5C", which it doesn't encode.

I have tried this in both Git Bash and Windows Command-line. I've tried it with and without the quotations. Same result.

Why isn't npm, or whoever, encoding %5C properly?

Comment: I am also getting same issue with npm 3.10.0