# Not able to install angularJS2 in visual studio behind proxy server

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

i am not able to start angularJS2 project in visual studio sitting behind a proxy server. the following steps which i have done are

1. installed node.js - v6.9.4
2. npm version is 3.10.10
3. set the npm config as

npm config set https-proxy=http://username:password@companyAddress:8080

and also tried this

npm config set https-proxy=http://"username:password"@companyAddress:8080 and also

4. i have a package.json file which was downloaded from here [package.json file downloaded link](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

now when i run the following command in the command prompt, navigating to the folder of my project, intially i get a loader like this

[image]

then it returns a error like this

[image]

I have even tried this npm config set proxy "http://domainName%5Cusername:password@company.com:8080/" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac) but it didnt work

I have tried all the blogs mentioned in stackoverflow as well as github, but nothing goes beyond the following steps and nothing resolved my issue.

Comment: does anyone has found a solution for this yet :)