# Config Proxy npm

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm-install

Hi Reamlente esoty tired of trying the proxy configuration for nodejs.To download packages this is my configuration

https-proxy
   https://cigb\johan:Yoannahermana87:proxy.cigb.edu.cu:8080/
http proxy
   https://cigb\johan:Yoannahermana87:proxy.cigb.edu.cu:8080/

And I still leave the same error and I do not know what I'm going to do for weeks on this, please help mee!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Comment: I already probe that and it does not work for me, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First of all I hope this is not your current password, if it is make sure to change it as soon as possible!

Is it possible that you typoed the `@` sign before the host in your proxy config. Usually you name a proxy like this:

```
<scheme>://<username>:<password>@<domain>:<port>
```

Which in my opinion resolves to the following in your case:

```
https://cigb%5Cjohan:Yoannahermana87@proxy.cigb.edu.cu:8080/
```

Although I do not know what the `\` means in your username, if it is supposed to be there url encode it to be safe with `%5C`.
To sum up the data you inserted:

Protocol/Scheme: https

Username: cigb\johan

Passwort: Yoannahermana87

Proxy-domain: proxy.cigb.edu.cu

Port: 8080