# Angular/cli installation Error

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

I am getting below huge error when trying to install @angular cli using npm 
I am working in a company network. This works when I create cli project at home.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-48_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-48_binding.node":

getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com:443

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@6.11.2 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.7" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2.7
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2.7 { Error: not found: python2.7
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2.7\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python2.7". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python2.7". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.failNoPython (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\nitin.shekhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
C:\Users\nitin.shekhar\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- @angular/cli@1.3.1
  `-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-sass@^4.3.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: _Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.[...]_ Did you try that?

Comment: I have set npm registery given by company

Comment: Not sure if that answers my question

Comment: see proxy things I have tried already it is not working

Comment: can you access file https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-48_binding.node in your browser?

Comment: @Kuncevic No I can not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto users directory of Windows and go to the directory which has your name
You will find a file called .npmrc

Edit it using any text editor.
add the following lines:

registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/

proxy=http:// username:password@ip:port

http-proxy=http:// username:password@ip:port

https-proxy=http:// username:password@ip:port

strict-ssl=false

Get your local proxy from your Networking or Field IT

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are behind a proxy server so npm cant access github
you need to configure your `npm` through your company proxy like:

```
npm config set proxy http://company-proxy-here:port
npm config set https-proxy http://company-proxy-here:port
```

for more details checkout [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Comment: Hi Sorry for the silly question As I am new to Angular and Npm..
company will be replace by name of my company and same for the port or I have to use at is..

Comment: @nitin-shekhar you need to find out what is your company proxy address and just replace with that. It could be even `proxy-ipaddress:port`. FYI `company-proxy` doesen't mean you have you replace `company` with your company name at all, it is just an example and port is usually like a number.