# Aurelia cli error in installing project dependencies

Tags: aurelia

What may be the reason for below error?

Installing project dependencies.

```
project1@0.1.0 F:\project1

+-- aurelia-tools@1.0.0
| `-- breeze-dag@0.1.0 and few more ...

Uncaught promise rejection:
{ Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\project1\node_modules\.stagi                                                                                                                ng\babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import-0934c411\package.json.2286576061' -> 'F:\p                                                                                                                roject1\node_modules\.staging\babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import-0934c411\packag                                                                                                                e.json'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: 'F:\\project1\\node_modules\\.staging\\babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-impor                                                                                                                t-0934c411\\package.json.2286576061',
  dest: 'F:\\project1\\node_modules\\.staging\\babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-impor                                                                                                                t-0934c411\\package.json',
  parent: 'project1' }
```

I m using git bash as administrator
node v 6.11.0

Comment: @harlandgomez i m not running running on proxy and there is no other instance of that project i m running cli for the very first project

Answer (score 0):

Error EPERM can mean many things. Since it's a permission error. You are probably running on a proxy, try uninstalling all proxy software and also disabling all your firewall. If this does not help you might need a config file the one stated here [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

It could also be that you probably have another instance of aurelia of that project locking it.