# Not Able to Install Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am getting below error while installing angular cli.
Please help me

```
 C:\Users\A737539>npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.3
    npm ERR! code E502
    npm ERR! 502 Parent proxy unreacheable: @angular/cli@6.1.3

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A737539\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-21T09_33_42_128Z-debug.log
```

Thanks,
Pushkar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac)

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119#issuecomment-3933333

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get npm work when on a proxy network :

create a **.npmrc** file with below fields :

```js
registry= //local artifactory site if any - remove if not
strict-ssl=false
cache=.\npmcache
prefix=.\npm
package-lock=false
loglevel=verbose
proxy= http://domain\username:password@servername:port/
https-proxy= http://domain\username:password@servername:port/
unsafe-perm=true
sass-binary-site= // if any local binary site is present - remove if not
```

Now place this file into mentioned location :  `C:\Users\A737539>` and then 
run `npm install` command it will work.
Once done , You can place this file inside repository (any new app created using cli) so that each time you don't have to set proxies manually.