# npm not working - URI error

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, uri, windows-7-x64

I just installed Node.js and npm (version 4.1.1, Windows 7 64 bit).  When I try any npm command, I get a URI error list, similar to that given here: [npm error question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164136/error-running-npm-command)
I see many people mentioning the proxy setting, but I cannot set the proxy in npm either; I get the same error for any npm command.  (My proxy settings appear to be correct in the .npmrc file in my user folder)
I have re-installed Node.js (making sure to delete AppData/Roaming npm files as well), to no effect.  I am and administrator on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
uninstalled node.js and npm, and deleted .npm files in User/username/AppData/Roaming folder

re-installed node.js/npm

then, in command line:

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

then removed reference in npmrc file (in users/username directory) to proxy:

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when I was under a company proxy.
The solution that worked for me:

- uninstall node
- remove everything from .npmrc file (usually , here is set the proxy)
  My .npmrc file was under users/user/.npmrc
- Restart computer
- Reinstall node
- Set the proxy again like this: [Using npm behind corporate proxy .pac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac/#answer-28218400)