# using npm with node.js windows 64 bit .exe version

Tags: node.js

Hi I've just downloaded the 64 bit version of the node.js on windows and I want to use npm to install a package for me, but when i open the node.exe terminal and 
write :
npm install sth
it gives me this error:
npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell.
what should I do?
how should I use npm with .exe version of the node.js?

Comment: The docs are misleading: npmjs.org says that npm is bundled with node, but when you download just the Windows .exe file, you're downloading a non-bundled version of NodeJS. I tried the .msi and it failed for me. This SO answer was helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300132/how-to-use-npm-with-node-exe#15924944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `npm` is an external command that should be used in the terminal, not node.exe repl. You should only use node.exe as repl - Read Print Eval Loop, or a tool where you input some javascript code and immediately see interpreted result, same as browser console (if you've ever used those to try out a javascript code snippet).

On windows, open `cmd` (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`), then run the command you were trying to run within node.exe, for example `npm update npm -g`.

Answer (score 0):

Run it from windows command shell
cmd.exe

If it doesn't work from there, you might want to look at the answers at:

[How to resolve 'npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476805/how-to-resolve-npm-should-be-run-outside-of-the-node-repl-in-your-normal-shell)