# Node Installed, But Neither Neither Node nor NPM Available Via Command Line

Tags: node.js, npm, xampp

I a using a laptop PC with the Windows 10 OS.

I am building web pages locally, via PHP/MySQL/JQuery (using the PHP 5.6 version of XAMPP).

I am trying to use npm in my command line (windows command prompt) but getting the following error: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Here is what I have done:
1.  Went to the following URL to install node.js (which should come bundled with npm):  https://nodejs.org/en/

2. Download the msi installer
3. Ran through the installer.

If I bring up node.js and try to install a package via mode (i.e. npm install gulp), it will return the message "npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell".

However, if I open my command line and type in "node -v", it appears that Node is not installed, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sigh*

As always, I managed to find the answer almost immediately after posting, despite actually searching beforehand.

Solution found here: [How to resolve 'npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476805/how-to-resolve-npm-should-be-run-outside-of-the-node-repl-in-your-normal-shell)

```
Do not run the application using node.js icon.
Go to All Programmes->Node.js->Node.js command prompt.
```