# Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Tags: windows, node.js, installation

I have Windows 7 32-bit. I installed the latest [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) 32 bit.
When I try to run the command `npm install jquery`, I receive the error:

> Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm

How does one resolve it?

Comment: Try running the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Run command prompt as administrator, and create the folder.

Comment: To remember the error, you can read it like "Error: NO ENTry". So check the directory whether it exists, otherwise create a new one. If there's no access, you can run the command prompt as administrator. Though for no access error node.js normally arise EACCESS error.

Comment: Googlers, also note, that you can get this message as an ‘not found answer’ to small path typos, i.e.  `res.sendfile('pathSlightlyWrong/posts.html')`  (experienced under Windows 7)

Comment: My Unhandled event error got fixed in this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441411/6665568

Comment: [Always scroll past the answer with 1,000 upvotes & read the rest of them...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494648/111307)

Answer (score 2007, accepted):

Manually creating a folder named 'npm' in the displayed path fixed the problem.

More information can be found on [Troubleshooting page](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-enoent-stat-cusersuserappdataroamingnpm-on-windows-7)

Comment: Seems like a bug on the instller.

Comment: Is this bug in some tracker? This makes for an awful first experience with nodejs...

Comment: This appears a bug with a recent release of Node.js. It wasn't an issue a few months ago. I had to manually create the folder to make it work on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: It's being tracked by https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5905, so you can subscribe to that issue to see progress.

Comment: After creating the missing directory, you can set the prefix to the right path using npm config get prefix / npm config set prefix xxxxx. Then you can remove the created directory again.

Comment: I logged in just to one up this.

Comment: @Dnaso, same here -- still relevant to latest download

Comment: I can confirm that this works on my laptop with 64bit Node, while the error reproduces on the Dell Venue with 32bit Node.

Comment: For those who land here later, this is a reported issue at [npm/npm#5905](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5905) and [joyent/node#8117](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8117)

Comment: I would introduce such a bug just to get the >3K points for this answer on SO :)

Comment: I had to *delete* the existing `npm` directory and then re-create it.

Comment: Had the same problem on Windows 7 64bit. Still not fixed. Maybe it has something to do with running cmd without admin rights?

Comment: Manually creating the directory and/or running the command as admin didn't work for me on Win7/64. I ran 'npm install [stuff]' without '-g' which worked. Now it also accepts '-g'.

Comment: still an issue on windows 7 and windows 8.1 , i always arrive here after installing node :)

Comment: @maryo: Can you please clarify: "After creating the missing directory, you can set the prefix to the right path using npm config get prefix / npm config set prefix xxxxx. Then you can remove the created directory again." What's the "right" path?

Comment: I've set it to D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm but that's because i use only one user account, previously it was set to something in  C:\Users\

Comment: My error path is 'path/to/out.min.js' and I just named a new folder called 'out.min.js' and it worked!! I'm still confused why that works, but it does...

Comment: for me what worked was, manually create a '.npm_modules' folder, because I already had the 'npm' folder

Comment: Year 2023, before seeing this answer, I thought updating to version 20 would fix it but it did not. unlikable "dev experience"

Comment: The same worked for node version 18.17.1

Comment: I confirm this fixes the issue for node v20

Comment: Such a strange but useful way.

Comment: It amazes me that this error still exists after 10 years. I just ran into this with a fresh installation of node on a blank windows 11.

Answer (score 180):

This can also be fixed by installing a node package manually.

```
npm install npm -g
```

The process of doing that will setup all the required directories.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me.  Need to use -g for 'Global Mode' so it installs the packages into your <nodejs application path>.  It will place them in the 'node_modules' folder.  Otherwise, it will run in local mode and attempt to place the files and directories into the whichever path you are currently in.  Sometimes, even running as administrator, you will run into directory access issues.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as well running Win 8.1 with the 64-bit installer. Thanks!

Comment: This is the cleanest solution!

Comment: this also worked when hitting the same problem on OSX, albeit with a different file path

Comment: I have just got the error, and found this to be the cleanest option to solve it!

Comment: this is the right answer! Thank you

Answer (score 114):

I ran into the same problem while installing a package via npm.

After creating the `npm` folder manually in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\` that particular error was gone, but it gave similar multiple errors as it tried to create additional directories in the `npm` folder and failed. The issue was resolved after **running the command prompt as an administrator**.

Comment: Yeah same for me -  Win7 and 64 bit. You need to create new folder and then execute npm command on command prompt run as administrator.

Comment: Same thing for me in Windows 10. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It worked after reinstalling node, removing npm and npm-cache folders in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\ and added the folders again in command prompt as an admin.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend setting an alternative location for your npm modules.

```
npm config set prefix C:\Dev\npm-repository\npm --global 
npm config set cache C:\Dev\npm-repository\npm-cache --global
```

Of course you can set the location to wherever best suits.

This has worked well for me and gets around any permissions issues that you may encounter.

Answer (score 4):

you need to creating a folder named 'npm' in the displayed path `C:\Users\$userName\AppData\Roaming\` fixed the problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the **Start Menu** and search the Node.js icon and open the shell and then install anything with

```
install <packagename> -g
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about installing the Npm package, this solution worked for me
Run the terminal in administrator
and tun command `npm install npm -g`
-g install package globally

Answer (score 0):

Install a stable version instead of the latest one, I have downgrade my version to `node-v0.10.29-x86.msi` from `'node-v0.10.33-x86.msi'` and it is working well for me!

http://blog.nodejs.org/2014/06/16/node-v0-10-29-stable/

Answer (score 0):

I needed a package from github that was written in typscript.  I did a git pull of the most recent version from the master branch into the root of my main project.  I then went into the directory and did an npm install so that the gulp commands would work that generates ES5 modules. Anyway, to make the long story short, my build process was trying to build files from this new folder so I had to move it out of my root.  This was causing these same errors.