# node.js and npm for windows

Tags: node.js, npm, command-prompt

I am trying to get node.js and npm working on a windows computer (It works perfectly fine for me on mac ox and ubuntu). The installation completed without any errors but when I try to install anything with npm I get the following error:

Example:

```
npm install express
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\siva.sivakumaran\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: This could help you i think [ENOENT,stat][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/nodejs-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Comment: Thanks! It looks like its a bug with the installer

Answer (score 4):

I added the folder npm under AppData/Roaming and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I solved it with:

`npm cache clean`

Best.

Comment: There is something wrong with the installer. I fixed the problem by using an older version of node