# nodejs- Error: ENOENT, stat when using npm in Windows8

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

Installed the latest node.js on Windows8. If I type

```
 npm -version
```

in the command console I correctly see

```
1.4.23
```

However, whenever I use the install command, regardless of the argument, I get the following error

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

What gives? Could this be a permissions issue or?

Answer (score 11):

you can just create an empty folder with "npm" name in path shown in Error

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I tried to install NPM on my work computer. I believe that there is a problem with the installer. I fixed this problem by installing an older version of NPM.

or you can add the folder npm under AppData/Roaming.

Look at this for more information:  [node.js and npm for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143432/node-js-and-npm-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem in Windows 8.1 MSDN-VM.

creating the **npm** Folder manualy fixed it for me. C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming**npm**