# Node.js error when starting with npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting error below after I tried to start node.js. Does anyone know the possible solution to the error below. I haven't used node.js at all. Please help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eri49.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the terminal as administrator before running the command the issue should be resolved

Comment: I tried to run as administrator, but still got the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the installer right now. You can try installing an older version of npm.
Or you can add an npm folder under AppData/Roaming.

Look at this for more information: [node and npm for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143432/node-js-and-npm-for-windows)

Comment: I have tried that and it works for my case. Thank you!