# hexo installation using npm error

Tags: node.js, npm, hexo

Here's [my previous quesstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143432/node-js-and-npm-for-windows)!

So after I created a folder npm in the appdata/roaming directory as people suggeested, I tried to install HEXO with npm using
    npm install -g hexo

but i am getting an odd error as attached below

http://i58.tinypic.com/f4o22f.png

I won't be able to use
    hexo version 
to check the version.

Has anyone experience before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot looks normal, it shows you the hexo package and all its dependecies (show in the form of a tree)

About the warning, it indicates that the module '[fsevents](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fsevents)' couldn't be installed. It is normal as fsevents is a module specific to Mac OSX and you're running windows.

So in conclusion, you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks, xShirase. I am completely new to hexo. :-)