# Error: npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm going through a tutorial of how to install everything I need to start a project of mine. Everything's going well until I'm in the cmd, I've created the 'PATH' and added everything, I have node.js, however the next step is to `npm install cordova` through the cmd. Though when I try this happens:

[image]

So I tried it on its own without having accessed node first and then this happened:

[image]

It's probably something really simple that I've done wrong. But the help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run `npm install xxx` in the REPL - the REPL is meant for testing out Node.js code, not running executables (well, npm).

Just run it like the [second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOXkx.png) you tried it. The fix to that can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095327/2708970).