# Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Tags: node.js, package, npm, command-prompt, init

I get this error when using "init npm" command in a newly installed Node.js

Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Comment: you need to manually create the directory. Possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/nodejs-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Comment: Note that the NPM command is [`npm init`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-init.html).

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT means the file does not exist. See http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html#error-handling