# Cordova Build Command Issue

Tags: cordova, build, command

Hello I am trying to run cordova build android command but I am getting following error

[image: Error]

I also reinstalled the cordova, but still this issue not fixed, while other cordova commands are running.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem: [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/nodejs-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)