# Node command seems to not be working in Windows

Tags: node.js

I just installed node.js and I also set PATH in environment variables. PATH value is:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\android\adt\sdk\platform-tools;C:\android\adt\sdk\tools;C:\wamp\www\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;`

In short term

`<jdk bin dir path>;<android platform-tools dir path>;<android tools dir path>;<apache ant bin dir path>;<nodejs path>`

Android command working properly.

but when I execute node command, it is not responding.

I wait for response around 30 minutes but nothing happened.

[image: after node command]

Now if I pressed enter then cmd look like below image:

[image: after pressing enter]

I am new with node.js. What is the issue?

Comment: Looks like it's working perfectly. The "node" program itself is simply an interpreter for the NodeJS language. You haven't given it any actual program to run.

Comment: hello , thanks for comment ,
actully i have to install ionic framework so i am following bellow video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNrNIHQ9cWo#t=480
my node command is not working as in video 
that's why i am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write just `node` your console enters "node mode" not bash or windows shell anymore. That is basically like a browser console, JavaScript welcome :)

What you want to do is run/open some ".js" file for example and do `node index.js`. That will run the code inside that `index.js`file.

Comment: hello , thanks for ans ,
actully i have to install ionic framework so i am following bellow video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNrNIHQ9cWo#t=480
my node command is not working as in video 
that's why i am confused.

Comment: @ManojPrajapat yeah, but your images look good. Just get out of the "node mode", back into having `c:\etc..` in your path and do `npm` where you did node before, It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I run command npm but it look like this : http://s30.postimg.org/ewon972s1/nodejs_error_3.png

Comment: @ManojPrajapat that is the next problem. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25093276/2256325

Comment: Thank you :) 
yes npm command run successfully ,
but the old problem still exist. 
node command has same issue.

Comment: @ManojPrajapat which old problem?

Comment: undefind after node command ?
please check image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/QJVXN.png 
and in video when press enter cmd back to its normal command area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65990/discussion-between-manoj-prajapat-and-sergio).

Comment: @ManojPrajapat but that is correct! Do `var x = 20;` you will also get undefined and the write just `x` that will print `20`. When the prompt is just `>` that means you are in node interpreter mode, wich accept JavaScript

Comment: now last question , how can i back from node mode ? 
mean which command bring me back to normal as when cmd lunched ?