# Getting this error when I am doing npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, spawn

I am totally new to this node.js!! How to overcome the following error . Tried all possible solutions given on net. And this error occurred after the environmental variables were changed. Please do help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
C:\project\nodetest1>npm start

> nodetest1@0.0.0 start C:\project\nodetest1
> node ./bin/www


npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\project\nodetest1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status -1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\project\nodetest1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\project\nodetest1\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

---

The package.json is

```
 {
  "name": "nodetest1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
 },
  "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
  "debug": "~2.0.0",
  "express": "~4.9.0",
  "express-session": "^1.9.3",
  "jade": "~1.6.0",
  "mongodb": "*",
  "mongoose": "^3.8.21",
  "monk": "*",
  "morgan": "~1.3.0",
  "nodemon": "*",
  "passport": "*",
  "passport-local": "*",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3"
 }
```

}

Comment: It's still unclear what are you trying to do. Npm start just runs scripts at your package. And we don't know nothing about your package and envs were changed

Comment: seems similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)

Comment: Can you post your NPM package.json file to identify the issue

Comment: example of start line : `"start": "node --harmony server.js"`

Comment: @satish The package.json file is attached above. Thankyou.

Comment: @ceadreak What will happen if we do harmony app.js? Thankyou for your reply.

Comment: `harmony` is used to enabled all V8 harmony features (ES compatibility, etc). Maybe you don't need it in your case. `node --v8-options` to see all v8 options

Comment: Are you sure the `./bin/www` file is where you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error had also occurred to me also.This happens because of path variable in enviroment .Therefore just change unistall node.js and remove the path variable from system and also Npm and npm-cache from the AppData\Roaming\npm . And then install node it will work for sure