# Use Autoprefixer with symfony2 and assetic on windows

Tags: css, symfony, prefix, assetic, autoprefixer

I have come to discover the superb Autoprefixer tool that adds all css prefixes to your css. Nice!
See it here : https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

I also discoverd there was a symfony bundle to make it work under assetic. See it here : https://github.com/bit3/assetic-autoprefixer

unfortunately, I am developping with a PC running windows so I can't run "sudo something" to install autoprefixer: "sudo npm install -g autoprefixer"

Does anyone know how I could install autoprefixer on windows 7 ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This other stack overflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm) might help. I don't develop on windows so I'm not 100% sure. Run as administrator is basically the same thing as sudo. Try opening your command prompt as Administrator first

Comment: so we have to install npm, it can't be installed standalone? and this will work with assetic?

Comment: npm is the 'Node Package Manager', so if you would like to install node packages then yes, you would need to install npm first

Comment: sorry I edited after your response. and in you experience, this will work with assetic that way? what is the executable here ? is node executing autoprefixer and transmitting the output to assetic ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Yes it does work with assettic, as I say I usually run this in linux and have the executable linked into the correct place to run, I'm not sure how that part would work on Windows machines