# NodeJS command "npm install express --save" raising exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have NodeJS installed and am trying to do this tutorial for making a NodeJS chat app:  http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I created the package.json file in it's own dedicated folder, and executed in the windows command prompt this npm command from the tutorial I linked.

```
npm install --save express@4.10.2
```

The error I receive is as follows:

**Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm'**

So I wemt to the ExpressJS page, tried the command they list on their site, which is.

```
npm install express --save
```

And I receive the same error.  Anyone know how to fix this, please?

Comment: Looks like npm doesn't have permission to that folder for some reason. I'm not on Windows so I'm afraid I can't give you much more advice than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)

Comment: Thanks both of you, especially you mido.  This is indeed a bug, the folder in the error message needs to be manually created, the installer isn't able to I guess (although I received no error messages during installation...), because of permission issues with creating that folder as Alexis suggested.  The link you posted solved my problem.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I work in Mac OSx encountered similar problem, run command as root user, should fix your problem.

Comment: sudoers do not get along well with windows.

Comment: Run command prompt as administrator on Windows.