# scripts/web-server.js is missing in AngularJs Seed and not able to run npm start

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-seed

I thought working Angular from Angular-Seed project since it contains good app structure and testing capability.

I have taken angular-seed master from the website (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) below i have screenshot of App for reference.

Since in angular-seed, it was not given clearly how to execute a webserver, I referred a tutorial npm website (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-seed), how to kick start angular-seed.

As said, I have installed node in my system and it is working fine, below you can find the screenshot. Then I tried to start the webserver using web-server.js in scripts folder but i couldn't find it. Thought of Starting the server (npm start) as given in Angular-Seed but unluckily there is an error.

Even in this [blog](https://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/setting-up-angularjs-angular-seed-node-js-and-karma/) i find there is a script folder but currently i couldn't find it in angular-seed-master.

Currently I'm totally gone how to proceed with it.

Could somebody help me on this or if anything i missed or wrongly understood.

Please let me know in case of further details.

**Node Instance**

[image]

**Npm Start Error**

[image]

**Angular-Seed and App Structure for reference**

[image]

[image]

**--------------------------------------EDIT: -----------------------------**

The above problem is solved, but there are other couple of issues occurred while using npm start. A detailed error given in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Ali Adravi,  as said Error: ENOENT has been resolved but there are other issues occurred while start of npm start.

Comment: @ Ali Adravi are you aware of this issue or else i miss anything