# TeamCity with npm - Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Tags: powershell, azure, npm, teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I'm having serious problems getting the last pieces of my TeamCity configuration in place.

I have a powershell step that executes the following commands:

```
& npm install
& grunt build
```

logging the following output:

```
Build (Powershell) (1s)
[13:18:08]PowerShell Executable: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[13:18:08]Working directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\6a434ee5d01fd0d9
[13:18:08]PowerShell arguments: [-NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell8407335260182621582.ps1]
[13:18:09]Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
[13:18:09]
[13:18:09]grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)
[13:18:09]Process exited with code 0
```

I've [seen](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1904) that this is a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm) problem, but none of the [solutions](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-enoent-stat-cusersuserappdataroamingnpm-on-windows-7) has worked for me so far.

My setup is the following: I have two virtual machines in Azure, `build` and `agent`. Both are connected to the same AD domain, `domain`, in which there is a user `domain\teamcityuser`, who is of "standard" class (i.e. not admin). This user runs both the build server (on the `build` instance) and the build agent (on the `agent` instance).

I've tried these things without success:

- Creating the directory in the error message, making sure that `domain\teamcityuser` has full controll access rights to it.
- Creating an `npm` directory under `C:\Users\teamcityuser\AppData\Roaming`
- Creating a file `C:\Windows\System32\config\SystemProfile\.npmrc` with the contents `prefix=C:\npm-global`, as well as creating the latter folder
- Running `npm cache clean` before running the build
- Installing a global `npm` package through `npm install -g npm`

What more can I try to get this working?

---

And to avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here's my actual problem:

I have a .NET Web API project with CI setup through this TeamCity installation, via Octopus Deploy and to the hosting server. I also have a github repo with the code for a web SPA that will consume the API. The spa is built with `grunt build`, after which there's a `dist` folder with everything I need to deploy.

I'd like to re-use as much as possible of the CI architecture to roll out the client too.

Comment: Did you try creating `npm` folder under system profile? `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that path to executable contains `SysWOW64`, this is an x32 Powershell, therefore, it refers to x32 system profile path, which is located at `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\config\systemprofile`. So, you need to use that path as your base in order to implement any workarounds, say, create `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder, and not plain `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Comment: Fantastic! That got me further, but not all the way :/ The build now fails at `npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\2d6d37d2-m-cache-lodash-2-4-2-package-tgz.lock'
 Move it away, and try again.` It stops there even if I remove all `npm-cache` folders, both in `system32`, `sysWOW64` and the user's `AppData`, before starting the build...

Comment: I did a brief search, that can be another bug https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6309 So far can't help further, I'm out of time.

Comment: Hm. Upgrading node (as suggested in that issue) seems to have helped with this. Thanks a lot!