# Ionic 2 - Error: EACCES: permission denied in installation on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I'm getting the following error while installing ionic on ubuntu 12.04 LTS following instructions in http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

**Commands used**

*install nodejs 6.x*

```
cookbook$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
cookbook$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
cookbook$ node -v
v6.9.1
[~]
cookbook$ npm -v
3.10.8
[~]
```

*install ionic per instructions*

```
cookbook$ npm install -g ionic cordova



+-- readable-stream@1.0.34 
| +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 
| +-- inherits@2.0.3 
| +-- isarray@0.0.1 
| `-- string_decoder@0.10.31 
`-- setimmediate@1.0.5 

npm ERR! Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/cookbook/npm-debug.log
[~]
```

The error message suggests to try running this command again as root/Administrator.

What is the right way to go about this ?

similar issue on windows 10 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40340990/3206440)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried different suggestions from different references.

**suggestion 1** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494648/3206440) - **didn't work**

This still gave the same error `EACCES: permission denied`

**suggestion 2** from [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) - **this worked**

```
cookbook$  npm config get prefix
/usr
[~]
cookbook$
```

so this is issue and npm's recommendation is to change npm's default directory to another directory

**Steps are as follows**

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`

After this ionic installation with `cookbook$ npm install -g ionic cordova` got completed without any errors.

```
cookbook$ ionic -v
--------------------------------
cordova -v******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
2.1.4

[~]
cookbook$ cordova -v
? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? Yes

Thanks for opting into telemetry to help us improve cordova.
6.4.0
[~]
cookbook$
```

Comment: The alternative method in suggestion 2 also works fine. In GNU/Linux just add `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global` in `~/.bashrc` file and ignore steps 2 to end in suggestion 2.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use sudo, it will bring more problems on the long term. The following guide explains it perfectly: (Its for OSX but applies the same)

https://johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/

Comment: +1 for the reference. from the article above, it seems this needs to be fixed in the long terms by npm folks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Comment: is this recommend way to do it ? does it have any side effects ? Ionic documentation doesn't seem to say this.

Comment: @Antonis - can you add reference / reason for running this as `sudo`

Comment: Ionic [does not recommend using sudo](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors) because "it can lead to further complications."